Individual manipulation of Multiple Objects on one Scene each tied to their own Image Target
I'm making a simple AR app and I have 8 image targets with one child object for each of them that gets displayed when they image target is being tracked by the camera. I can only track one image target at a time. I'm also using LeanTouch to rotate and pinch scale the objects. Now, I have two questions:

How can I reset each object to their initial state when their respective image target is not being tracked?

How can I manipulate each object independently of each other? As of now whenever I rotate one object, then scan a different image target it will display its assigned object with the same orientation as the first one I rotated.


Example:
1st image (rotated)
2nd image (it's like this when I tracked the image target
I tried using this script:
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class ResetPositionOnTrackingLost : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ObserverBehaviour observerBehaviour;
    private Vector3 initialPosition;
    private Quaternion initialRotation;
    private Vector3 initialScale;

    void Start()
    {
        observerBehaviour = GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();
        if (observerBehaviour)
        {
            observerBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnTargetStatusChanged;
        }

        // Store the initial position, rotation, and scale of the object
        initialPosition = transform.localPosition;
        initialRotation = transform.localRotation;
        initialScale = transform.localScale;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (observerBehaviour)
        {
            observerBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged -= OnTargetStatusChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnTargetStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour behaviour, TargetStatus status)
    {
        if (status.Status == Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            // Target lost, reset position, rotation, and scale
            ResetTransform();
        }
    }

    public void ResetTransform()
    {
        transform.localPosition = initialPosition;
        transform.localRotation = initialRotation;
        transform.localScale = initialScale;
    }
}

But it did not reset the models to their initial state once I removed the image target out of the camera's line of sight then put it back again in front of the camera.

If extended tracking is enabled the Status might be LIMITED and not NO_POSE

In general why reset to initial transforms instead of just keeping the latest stable known one?

I want to reset them to initial transforms whenever tracking is lost mainly for when changing image targets so that they would not have the same transforms as the others (the 2 screenshots I included on the question being an example of it).
